# ReactJs variables return a static text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables

hello i have this piece of code in reactjs :

```
{props.slices[2].transform === '1' ? '10' : props.slices[2].transform.replace('0.','')}
```

i need to stock it in a variable to use it in another reactjs file  so i did this :

```
 this.testVarible= {props.slices[2].transform === '1' ? '10' : props.slices[2].transform.replace('0.','')}
```

but it doesn't seem to work, 
 the resule of this is :  this.testVarible=2
i have also try to do :

```
 this.testVarible= {{props.slices[2].transform === '1' ? '10' : props.slices[2].transform.replace('0.','')}}
```

but i get errors .

Comment: `to use it in another reactjs file` what do you mean?

Comment: I can make sure that the problem you have is not from `{props.slices[2].transform === '1' ? '10' : props.slices[2].transform.replace('0.','')}`. So please provide some more context. This `{props.slices[2].transform === '1' ? '10' : props.slices[2].transform.replace('0.','')}` looks very lengthy, but doesn't give much context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use function instead of variable. Let's say you've built a function in **utils.js**

***utils.js***

```js
export const getTestVariable = (value) => (
  value === '1' ? '10' : value.replace('0.', '')
)
```

And then you can import this function in any react file and use it

```
import { getTestVariable } from './utils.js'
...
const testVariable = getTestVariable(props.slices[2].transform)
```